# Users and Groups graphic application crashes on Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, system-settings, user-management

I need to modify 'User Privileges' at 'Advanced Settings', in '*Users and Groups*' application.

To get this application, I installed from terminal, 'gnome-system-tools', at Ubuntu 16.04, and reboot the system.

Then, I launched the graphic app, '*Users and Groups*', but it always crashes before been launched completely.

**What can be the root cause of these crashes?**

I have removed and reinstalled the 'gnome-system-tools', upgraded the system, drivers, etc, but it does not work.

**Is there any way to view and modify all 'User Privileges'?**

Comment: Try running `users-admin` in terminal - what is the output ?

Comment: "(users-admin:4579): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.system-tools.users' is not installed"
But I do not understand why is telling that 'system-tools' is not installed.

Comment: Try installing the `gsettings-desktop-schemas` package.

Comment: Prompt says it is already installed.